# Error Installing pip Inside Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, pip, containers

So I tried to download pip inside a docker container by first copying the installation file via

> docker cp get-pip.py dock:get-pip.py

and then I went into the container

> docker exec -it 58 bash

I then tried to python get-pip.py the file and i get the following error.

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/pip/

Comment: Why you don't use the oficial python image? If you explain what are you triying to do, maybe we can help you.

Comment: @German the docker container I'm using right now is a database container that I'm testing. When I try to do docker pull python I get the error: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Comment: Did you try restart the docker process? Beacuse the only way i got this error  is when I dont have internet connection.

Comment: @German restarting the docker process doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: It's wired... Can you open the url in a browser?

Comment: {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}

Comment: Is there any proxy between you and the Internet? Can you also let us know what Docker version you are using and how it was installed (native Linux, Docker for Mac, Docker Machine, etc)?

Comment: I just restarted my computer and the issue fixed itself. It didn't work earlier when I did docker restart [container] but it seems to be working just fine now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the docker process had problems connecting to the internet. So the installation of pip manually had errors.

Solution Process:

- Restart the docker process. (Not working)
- Restart the computer. (problem solved)